# Unmarshall should return error when having wrong json input structure

Tags: json, go, struct, marshalling, unmarshalling

I have struct A and B. When a JSON string A is unmarshalled to struct A then it is valid, however if the JSON string A is unmarshalled to struct B it is still successful (which should not).

Is there any way to detect that wrong JSON input has been wrongly converted to a wrong struct type?

Please look at the code below: [play](https://play.golang.org/p/uoOX9jUbJEK)

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)

type A struct {
    Name string `json:"name"`
    Age  int    `json:"age"`
}

type B struct {
    Alamat string `json:"alamat"`
    Umur   int    `json:"umur"`
}

func main() {
    var structA A
    var structAA A

    valA := "{\"name\":\"budi\",\"age\":10}"
    valB := "{\"alamat\":\"jakarta\",\"umur\":120}"

    //correct case
    err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(valA), &structA)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("fail unmarshal")
    }

    fmt.Println(structA.Name)
    fmt.Println(structA.Age)

    //unmarshalled successfully but with wrong json
    err = json.Unmarshal([]byte(valB), &structAA)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("fail unmarshal")
    }

    fmt.Println(structAA.Name)
    fmt.Println(structAA.Age)

}
```

Comment: It did not fail, but it didn't unmarshall either. `Unmarshall` couldn't find wanted fields and `structAA` stayed empty.

Comment: Maybe try this https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Decoder.DisallowUnknownFields?

Comment: I have looked at this option, however the decoder requires stream input (io.Reader)., that during processing data should be copied first from stream. Do you have sample of implementation?

Comment: @BondhanNovandy Use strings.NewReader to get io.Reader from the string.  https://play.golang.org/p/AFdVv8u2HVS

Comment: @BondhanNovandy `io.Reader` doesn't have to be a stream, for example turn your strings into readers using this https://golang.org/pkg/strings/#NewReader

Comment: @mkopriva thanks. dx := json.NewDecoder(strings.NewReader(jsonData)), here, will it impact performance? as there are twice creating new objects a Reader and A decoder?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Referring the [docs](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Unmarshal), `json.Unmarshal(data []byte, v interface{})`, by default, does not work in the way you suppose:

> By default, object keys which don't have a corresponding struct field are ignored (see Decoder.DisallowUnknownFields for an alternative).

So, JSON properties `alamat` and `umur` in your `valB` are ignored as they are not matched in struct `A` and `name` and `age` are set to their type default.

Comment: I will accept this answer. However full solution is given by @mkopriva in https://play.golang.org/p/AFdVv8u2HVS (see comments on my questions above)